# Backbone: clear all data from memory

Tags: backbone.js, view, destroy

I have a menu that upon click, creates a backbone view and binds controls.  This happens every time I click on the menu.  What I need to know is to how clear backbone objects from memory before the view is defined and rendered (on each menu click).

Otherwise, every time the menu is clicked, backbone creates a new view and rebinds all the controls.  So I get something like this:

```
r {cid: "view1", options: Object, $el: b.fn.b.init[1], el: div#templatePlaceholder, constructor: function…}
r {cid: "view2", options: Object, $el: b.fn.b.init[1], el: div#templatePlaceholder, constructor: function…}
r {cid: "view3", options: Object, $el: b.fn.b.init[1], el: div#templatePlaceholder, constructor: function…}
```

note: the DOM only shows one render

EDIT:
Code:

```
            var app = {
                Collection: Backbone.Collection.extend({}),
                Model: Backbone.Model.extend({}),
                View: Backbone.View.extend({
                    initialize: function(){
                        this.setElement($('#templatePlaceholder'));
                    },
                    render: function () {
                        var that = this;
                        Q.when(formDataGet.execute()).then(function (data) {
                            that.$el.html(data);
                       });
                    },
                    events: {
                        "click button[id=lbtn]": "goLeft",
                        "click button[id=rbtn]": "goRight"  
                    },

                    goLeft: function () {
                        // Button clicked
                        console.log(this);
                    },
                    goRight: function () {
                        // Button clicked
                        console.log(this);
                    }

                }),

            };


            var view = new app.View({
            });

            view.render();
```

This code gets fired every time a menu item is clicked.
And this creates a new view.

Comment: I am doing something very basic.  I can remove the view as long as I pass the view object to the remove().  But when I click my menu, it has no way of knowing what the view object is.  Perhaps i can remove a view by ID.  That would help.  But it would be best if I can remove all the backbone views outside of the backbone scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two ways in core backbone (there are probably more, but it's a start)

1. Hold a reference to the view, when you need to close the menu, call [`remove()`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-remove) on the view
2. You don't have to remove the view, you can simply show / hide it, nothing wrong with it
3. Use Marrionette / Chappline / LayoutManager that have some strucured ways to maintain your views

More information about your app / structure and what are the use cases will allow me to help more

Comment: Thanks Eran, I am not closing views with backbone.  My app is not a backbone app.  Actually, I am using Durandal to route between Views,  In one of the pages I have a tree view.  This tree view (onclick), calls the script above that creates a backbone model etc and renders the view.  Each time a treeview node is clicked, the entire backbone script is ran again and a new model is created and a new view is loaded.  So I am not managing the lifecycle of each backbone model/view instance within backbone.  I need a way to destroy backbone from outside of the backbone context.

Comment: So far I have succeeded in unbinding by using  jquery.unbind().   If I could also find a way  of deleting all backbone objects from memory on each treeview click,  that would be ideal

Comment: backbone doesn't have a "clear all" method, it's up to you, you'll need to have an object that holds the view instances (e.g. a data attribute on the element, a bit ugly, but let's ignore it) then call .remove() on each view, then if you want it garbage collected, you'll need to remove references to that view, either by removing the data attribute, or if it's in an object do a `delete viewholder.view1` etc... that's the backbone way, check Marionette / Layout Manager (or use jstree and forget about doing this in backbone ;))

Comment: Thank Eran, I'll try marionette